# Software to share serial port over network

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, hardware

Is it possible to share serial port over the network? I need to access my serial device from remote computer. I have no opportunity to connect to it physically. I need a software for remote access to serial port.

Comment: Any cost requirements? Add your budget or `[tag:gratis]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was to share the port over network - linux and windows machines, so my answer for the question is [Serial over LAN software](http://www.serial-com-port.com).

Really works, crossplatforming, but rather expensive.

Comment: It costs $495.90

Answer (score 2):

In my last company I was using [Pira CZ Remote COM port](http://www.pira.cz/show.asp?art=piracom).

It is available free of cost and works on Windows 7. If it doesn't work with your USB-to-serial converter, buy a better one. There are lots of crappy USB-to-serial converters out there.

The license is a bit unclear. It just says:

> The software is provided as is, without warranty of any kind. The author shall not be liable for damages of any kind. Use of the software indicates you agree to this. You are prohibited from renting, modifying or reverse engineering of the software.

IIRC, I have contacted the author and asked if commercial use (use in the company internally) is ok. You should probably do the same, just to be sure.

Comment: Uh, how is that license unclear? It doesn't specify any usage restrictions, you just can't tinker with its internals (according to the license at least) or rent it to someone (why would you do that anyway)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: well, if the license is clear, so much the better. For me, it was not a "well known" license like Apache, BSD, GPL etc. and I'm neither a a native speaker nor a laywer, so I asked for it.

Comment: Is it possible to autostart the software at Windows logon? Or better to use as a service?

Comment: Thanks, but I needed the crossplatforming solution